# How to change icon on tap on it in flutter

Tags: flutter, icons

I'm trying to change the icon when tap on it, but it is not working.
I'm trying to implement the Wishlist scenario on it.

Intially icon is `favorite_outline`, and when I tap on it, value of `productsList[index].isFav` changes to `true`, but not displaying `favorite` icon.

here is my code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ProductsList> productsList = ProductsList.getProducts();
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: productsList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  Container(child: 
                      productsList[index].isFav
                          ? IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  productsList[index].isFav = false;
                                });
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite))
                          : IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  productsList[index].isFav = true;
                                });
                                print(productsList[index].isFav);
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline))),
            ))));
  }
```

here is the ProductList class

```
class ProductsList {
  int id;
  String productName;
  bool isFav;

  ProductsList(
      {required this.id,
      required this.productName,
    ,required this.isFav});

  static List<ProductsList> getProducts() {
    return <ProductsList>[
      ProductsList(
        id: 1,
        productName: "Samsung Microwave",
        isFav: false
      ),
      ProductsList(
        id: 2,
        productName: "Dji Drones",
        isFav: false
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

please help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setState`, your `build` widget rebuild and

`List<ProductsList> productsList = ProductsList.getProducts();`

call again and your `product` list, set again as default:

```
ProductsList(id: 1, productName: "Samsung Microwave", isFav: false),
ProductsList(id: 2, productName: "Dji Drones", isFav: false),
```

You should use `ChangeNotifier` and `notifyListeners()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ProductsList> productsList = ProductsList.getProducts();
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: productsList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  Container(child: 
                      productsList[index].isFav
                          ? IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                            if(productsList[index].isFav){
                               setState(() {
                                  productsList[index].isFav = false;
                                });
                                }else{
                                setState(() {
                                  productsList[index].isFav = true;
                                });
                              }},
                              icon:productsList[index].isFav? Icon(Icons.favorite):Icon(Icons.favorite_outline))
                          ),
            ))));
  }
```

Comment: is this code worked for you? not working for me.